# How to understand confinement of 2+1d $U(1)$ gauge theory from instanton effects?

Tags: gauge-theory, path-integral, instantons, confinement

In Section 6.3.2 of XG Wen's book *Theory of Quantum Many-body System*, the confinement of $2 + 1 d$ compact $U \left( 1 \right)$ gauge theory was explained by the instanton effect. I want to know how to include the instanton configuration into the path integral formalism. Could anyone provide me with the solution of Ex. 6.3.3?

Comment: You can find the details of this calculation in Polyakov's original paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(77)90086-4